# Isuzu Elf Double Cab Dashboard light

Tags: isuzu

What does this mean? Need your help. Ive searched all the signs already [image: Ja]

Comment: Which one? the one with the coil (in orange) is usually for engine heaters

Comment: What model year, and in what country? The manuals I can find for recent versions of this truck in the United States do not have either of those symbols.

Answer (score 2):

Symbol on the top one is for represent Isuzu's Clutch Free system faulty. Needs be checked and recalibrated.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!